# How to find the web-part with it's id in a web-part page

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I have a web-part page in which i have three zones zone1,zone2 and zone3.Each of these zones have user controls.I want a specific user control not to render depending on the setting i have in database.
If anybody have idea.Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to override the RenderWebPart method of WebPartChrome class.In that method you can check the setting from database and decide whether to render the web-part or not.In that method you also have the webpart.uniqueid that uniquely identify the webparts within any zone.Hope this will help someone.If somebody have still problems you can email me.